# Risk register for 'office-based' research

Tags: projects, funding

I'm writing a grant application for a 1.5-year research project in which

- I'm the only member
- a systematic literature review (some papers may be pay-walled) will be performed
- the main study data (de-identified) have been already collected in a previous study
- the only required logistics are an average computer (already provided by the University) and open source software.

Of course, the application includes conference presentations, travel to meet collaborators, and open-access publications, etc.

From the funders' perspective, what kind of risks that should be addressed in such a research project?

Comment: Is the funder asking about risks to human subjects?  Your local IRB or equivalent would presumably find that the risks to human subjects from this kind of meta-analysis were tiny or non-existent.

Comment: Which funder? The funder I work for would view your team (if it really is just you being funded on the project) as too weak and risky to give money too. Others might have a different view, especially if your project is cheap.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there could be many, but:

- The existing data might not be good quality or sufficient quantity.
- Reliance on a single person may lead to failure if they have health problems, or get a new job.

Comment: Thanks. How these risks could be effectively addressed in the application?